# How does Kakao Talk work?

Tags: android, instant-messaging, whatsapp

I have been doing some research to create an **IM application**. I saw many sample codes and still trying to decide which method to use. Before starting development I want to ask your opinion if anybody knows how popular IM applications such as **Kakao Talk, Line, We Chat, WhatsApp** work.

I saw some articles saying to use **Google Cloud**, and some articles about using **XMPP.**

I am a kinda new for Android development and before starting development I want to see all my possibilities and choose best method for that.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I would presume they don't all work the same way. There are different techniques one can use to implement a chat client. Each of these companies might have their own proprietory technologies depending on their scale, user base, finances etc.

2 popular options you can check out are :

- [XMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP) - It's supported by most major chat clients and is used by the likes of Facebook (a customized version of it anyway). [asmack](https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack) is a popular XMPP library for Android which might be useful to you.
- A Backend-As-A-Service (BAAS) provider like [Parse](https://parse.com/). This will save you a lot of server side heavy lifting and writing backend code like you would have to do if you were considering something like [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/)

If this is a learning project, I would suggest implementing a very simple client and writing both the server and client-side code so that you know how the whole stack works. Hope that helps!

Comment: It is not really learning project, I made small apps for myself to practice. This time I want to start a big project with a group of developers. As you know Kakao talk is popular in Korea, and some other apps popular in their country. I will try to make similar thing for my country. So we can't say small project, maybe it will start as a small project but my goal is to make it bigger. That's why I want to make a good start. Thanks for your answer